# Как раздать сайт с компьютера по WiFi (ArchLinux)?

Tags: wifi, archlinux

Можно ли раздать сайт с wi-fi?

К примеру чтоб можно было запустить RubyOnRails на локалке и на сайт можно было зайти с мобильного телефона

P.S.

1. Обычно wifi точку создаю с помощью [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) командой `sudo create_ap wlp3s0 enp2s0 MyAccessPoint passphrase`
2. Компьютер-раздатчик сам подключен к wifi-точке

Comment: А в чем проблема получить доступ по IP устройства? Тем более по локальному, тут даже порты открытые не нужны. Сам так делаю

Comment: @smellyshovel, если не трудно, можете написать руководство?

Comment: Ну блин. Узнаете IP адрес своего устройства, на котором висит сайт (ПК, насколько я понял). Пускай он будет 192.168.1.2. Открываете браузер на мобильном, пишете в строке 192.168.1.2:3000 (3000 - это порт, насколько я знаю, это порт стандартного App-сервера Rails Webrick'а. Ну и все, вроде бы

Comment: @smellyshovel, не получилось, узнал ip компьютера на http://myip.com.ua/, но с мобилки зайти не получилось, not aviable, request too long, компьютер и мобильный подключены к одному роутеру, роутер к провайдеру, но провайдер вроде бы использует забыл-как-называется протокол, который увеличивает количество доступных ip-адресов внутри сети, запоминая порт входа (давно читал), может дело в этом?

Comment: нет, ip моего компьютера и мобильного одинаковые

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете разницу между внешним IP и внутренним. Мой внешний IP на данный момент - 93.85.138.xxx, и он меняется при каждой перезагрузке роутера. А мой внутренний IP постоянен и привязан к определенному устройству в домашней сети. И именно по ВНУТРЕННЕМУ IP  я могу получить доступ к любому устройству внутри сети.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41385/discussion-between-smellyshovel-and-bjornmelgaard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо @smellyshovel (так я людей еще не задалбывал), решение [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592416/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ip)