# Как зайти на локальный сайт с по ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iptables, ethernet

Хочу заходить на сайт на компе (рельсы, http://localhost:3000) с мобилки, подключено все к wifi

- ip провайдера (внешний, из myip.ru) - `195.184.199.162`
- ip роутера (gateway) - `192.168.1.1`
- ip мобилки (internal ip) - `192.168.1.6`
- ip компа - inet `192.168.1.92/24`

---

1. мобилка и комп как положено пингуют друг друга, когда они подключены к инету и не пингуют когда нет
2. комп заходит через браузер на сайт через локалхост, 127.0.0.1, **НО НЕ ЧЕРЕЗ** свой внутренний ip (хотя по идее должен, так?)
3. фильтры iptables чисты
4. 192.168.1.92:3000 c мобилки cannot be reached (и с компа как я говорил)

---

Вопрос: мне нужно открыть порт через iptables? Как это сделать?

Пробовал `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp —dport 3000 -j ACCEPT`, а также скрипт [отсюда](http://www.adodo.ru/blog/linux/79.html)

Comment: посмотрите, слушает ли ваша программа другие адреса помимо 127.0.0.1. как посмотреть, написано даже по приведённой вами же ссылке.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin [вывод](http://pastebin.com/raw/hGWY9bEi), видимо нет, это при чистом iptables (iptables.sh не применен), [iptables.sh который применял](http://pastebin.com/raw/rm1PZCkY)

Comment: Посмотрите конфиги веб-сервера, что бы он случал на всех адресах а не только на 127.0.0.1. А iptables тут скорее всего вообще не причем

Comment: воу, вы оказались правы) @Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Mike, проблема оказалась в самом веб-сервере, решение

rails s -b 192.168.1.92 (ip компьютера)

Answer (score 1):

Стоит попробовать в настройках сервера заменить `127.0.0.1` или `localhost` на **`0.0.0.0`**.

Comment: Нет, если написать `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`, то с мобилки не заходит.А вообще проблема уже решена, я написал ответ, спасибо)